# FormsModules is not found Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am trying to import FormsModules in angular 5 appmodule but it is giving me error: *FromModule is not found*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';                
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';                    
import { FormsModules } from '@angular/forms';                
import { ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';            
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';                    
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';        


@NgModule  ({


  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent

  ],


  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModulesenter code here
  ],    

providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})        

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported wrong modules. Please try below code

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

For More info visit: https://angular.io/guide/forms